# How can I build package in OpenWRT BuildRoot

Tags: linux, cross-compiling, openwrt, buildroot

I have installed on CentOS the OpenWRT BuildRoot for crosscompile. In menu config I've chosen architecture of my OpenWRT device and now I don't know how to build a HelloWorld package to deploy on my device.
Can someone tell me step-by-step instruction what actions I have to do?

[UPD]: I need *.ipk to install by opkg.

Comment: Please edit your post to mention the package format you want, and the package managing tool you will use for installing the package. Example : Create a package.ipk http://dev.leipzig.freifunk.net/svn/firmware/packages/mkipkg , and install it with `opkg` https://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/techref/opkg

Comment: Yes, I need ipk package and it will be installed by opkg. I tried to make package with helloworld program compiled on CentOS, but it doesn't work on OpenWRT (other architecture is the reason)

Comment: You will of course have to cross compile your program with the  OpenWrt cross-compiler , before you make the package.

Comment: If I try to execute cross-compiled app on CentOS (not on target OpenWRT device), should it work?

Comment: ? Which architecture is your "OpenWRT OS" ? arm ? armhf ? arm64 ? .... No executable for arm* will run with your x86 CentOS ( i686 or x86_64)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for very broad question - I'm just a beginner in linux crosscompiling.
Now I can build my own packages for target device. Problem was:
Make command in openwrt buildroot directory was finished with errors, but some files for crosscompilation were built. I had to finish make command without errors and then compile my custom package. There were many simple problems while executing make command, but google and openwrt.org forum helped me.

Thanks to @Knud Larsen and his comments, that help me to find the solution!